# Sending an int value on a TCP socket connection

Tags: c++, tcp

All I would like to do is send an integer via a socket but it seems the sendto socket command only accepts a char. I am struggling at changing my int into a char to send it via the socket. request_number is the int I want to change into the char which is request_char.

I don't have access to the atoi/atof etc commands so here I tried sprintf. But when I run it does nothing and won't even printout the value. What am I doing wrong with my sprintf command? Or is there any other way to avoid this conversion when sending an int on a tcp socket?

```
 int request_number= 100;
 char request_char[request_number];

    sprintf(request_char, "%i", request_number); 
    send(tcp_new_socket , request_char , strlen(request_char) , 0);
```

Also, when I receive the value on the other end of my socket, how do I turn it back into an int? The same type of sprintf command?? Thanks in advance for any help. Let me know if I need to elaborate on anything.

Comment: You need to design a protocol before you implement one. Take a look at the specifications for other protocols layered on top of TCP (such as HTTP, IRC, or SMTP) to see how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

> All I would like to do is send an integer via a socket but it seems the sendto socket command only accepts a char.

Wrong. It accepts a `char *`.

> I am struggling at changing my int into a char to send it via the socket.

Of course you are. An `int` won't fit into a `char`, and you don't need to do it. Just provide the address of the `int` and cast it to `char *`.

```
int request_number= 100;
char request_char[request_number];

sprintf(request_char, "%i", request_number); 
send(tcp_new_socket , request_char , strlen(request_char) , 0);
```

This code doesn't agree with the description you have given. There is nothing here that converts an `int` into a `char`. There is code that converts it into a `char[]` *array*, to be sent as ASCII, but that's not what you said you were trying to do. To just send the `int` in binary:

```
int request_number = 100;
send(tcp_new_socket , (char*)&request_number , sizeof request_number, 0);
```

and conversely at the receiver. However you should really send the `int` in network byte order:

```
int request_number = htons(100);
send(tcp_new_socket , (char*)&request_number , sizeof request_number, 0);
```

and use `ntohs()` at the receiver to put it back into host order.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform the conversion. A socket can send any kind of data. Just cast the int address to a char* and give the socket the pointer and byte count.

Answer (score -1):

Anything which is sent to network will be in bytes... so unsigned bytes are chars so you see send API being as char array.

On the other side you will receive bytes now based on protocol [as defined by you]
when you receive you need to construct int type from the bytes

hope this helps

Comment: why is downvote? pls explain i provide details on why network api is byte array and what to be done on recieve side..